# Soundcloud Apple Mach-O Linker error when running from Iphone device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, soundcloud

My program runs fine when i use the simulator however, when i try run it on an ios Device i get the apple mach-o linker error. This only started to happen when i added the soundcloud api

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: What does your iOS thing have to do with Cocoa?  What is Cocoa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the library you are linking against (Soundcloud) was not built for arm64. It looks like some of your other dependancies (like JSONKit) were also not built for arm64.

If you change your build architectures to only build for the architectures you can support (armv7, armv7s), that is one way of fixing the problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same issue, except this solution did not work for me. 
When I built using the standard architectures, the message was "Undefined symbols for architecture 86_64", when I changed the architectures to armv7 and armv7s, the message changed to "Undefined symbols for architecture i386"
Any ideas?

Comment: You are linking against a binary that does not support the iOS simulator @relatively_slow

Comment: I find that hard to believe, Im linking to the SoundCloud iOS SDK and it's dependancies, which, as I understand, support the simulator

Comment: Your linker error is saying exactly that: "I have no x86_64 binary to link against for this symbol". You can verify this with lipo.

Comment: But how can this be? I know many people that use the simulator to test SoundCloud based applications...